# Tsconfig "files" not being referenced properly

Tags: typescript, webstorm

My problem is that I can't figure out why my .ts files aren't being referenced from my tsconfig.json file. I want to be able to use the tsconfig instead of in-file references `/// <path= ....`

Here is my config files:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "files": [
    "home.ts"
  ]
}
```

I tried all sorts of file paths to home.ts, but I get the same error every time, which is that the correct module can't be found. When I put it back in the reference path, everything works again. Any ideas? (I DO have my webstorm set to use my tsconfig file.)

Comment: If you specify 'files' property you need add to the property all referenced files. Otherwise you can skip the property and then all files in the directory will be covered by tsconfig

Answer (score 0):

Your config is *right*. See demo below:

[image]

> (I DO have my webstorm set to use my tsconfig file.)

Then its a bug in webstorm and should be reported.